# Can't pull docker image: no route to host

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker

When using `boot2docker` on OSX, I can't pull a new image from Docker Hub:

```
$ docker run mysql
Unable to find image 'mysql' locally
Pulling repository mysql
2014/06/24 16:58:18 Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/mysql/images: dial tcp: read udp 192.168.0.1:53: no route to host
```

I can still access that URL using a browser or `curl`. What gives?

Comment: I get this error from time to time, too. But I think it has sth to do with docker hub itself.

Answer (score 5):

Restarting `boot2docker` fixed it for me. I think it had to do with switching wifi networks using different IP ranges.

```
$ boot2docker restart
```